# Xero API SocketTimeoutException

Tags: xero-api, socket-timeout-exception, xero

I am facing below issue while fetching data from Xero.

`javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException:java.net.SocketTimeoutException: SocketTimeoutException invoking`

https://api.xero.com/api.xro/2.0/Payments?page=1: connect timed out

I have below configuration for timeout parameters,

```
xeroConnectionTimeout = 60 sec

xeroReceiveTimeout = 300 sec
```

Comment: anyone to help here

Comment: Xero seems to have a strangely silent dev community... is your app returning this error when connected just to the demo company?

Comment: yes, but not a demo company. App is able to fetch data iteratively based on page but after some iterations it starts failing.

Comment: Interesting twist. Just thinking out loud ... Can you rule out API limit issues and non-existent page by altering timing and starting page...